# @property int value can't change,is really wierd,and i can't find the solution

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a button to invoke the change of a int value declared in @interface.here is my code of interface.

```
@interface CheckInController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) int checkInDate;
@end
```

the code of button's selector

```
- (void)checkin {
    self.checkInDate++;
    NSLog(@"checkInDate: %d",_checkInDate);
}
```

whatever times I click the button,the console panel shows like this

```
2017-08-01 16:46:39.631 HeJing[1888:64607] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 16:46:40.057 HeJing[1888:64607] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 16:46:40.342 HeJing[1888:64607] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 16:46:40.578 HeJing[1888:64607] checkInDate: 0
```

after that i assign some int value like this

```
self.checkInDate = 1;
NSLog(@"checkInDate: %d",_checkInDate);
```

the console panel always show

```
2017-08-01 17:06:38.182 HeJing[1991:75284] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 17:06:39.101 HeJing[1991:75284] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 17:06:39.255 HeJing[1991:75284] checkInDate: 0
2017-08-01 17:06:39.401 HeJing[1991:75284] checkInDate: 0
```

did I do something wrong?
the code above all run in the `.m` file.
and my setter method

```
- (void)setCheckInDate:(int)checkInDate {
    NSString *infoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"已连续签到%d天，再坚持%d天就可以积分翻倍哦!",_checkInDate,6 - _checkInDate];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.97 green:0.44 blue:0.13 alpha:1.00] range:NSMakeRange(5, 2)];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.97 green:0.44 blue:0.13 alpha:1.00] range:NSMakeRange(11, 2)];
    _checkInInfoLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Comment: `self.checkInDate` vs `_checkInDate`. Do you have a `@synthetize` somewhere?

Comment: why need a `@synthesize` ,I declare a `@property` and I did'n override both getter and setter method, I only override setter method

Comment: `I only override setter method` Where is that code?

Comment: In `- (void)setCheckInDate:(int)checkInDate`, it's missing `_checkInDate = checkInDate` before `infoString` (or after, it depends on what you really want to do, but usually logic would make it before)

Comment: question updated

Comment: oh my god,I'm so stupid,thanks guy.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a custom setter by overriding `- (void)setCheckInDate:(int)checkInDate`.

So when you write `self.checkInDate = 1;`, it's calling the custom setter.
But in that setter you didn't write `_checkInDate = checkInDate`.
Adding this should fix your issue.